# Why two simplices become equal in the colimit

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, proof-explanation, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

The following is an image of a proof found in Hovey's *Model Categories*, for which my question concerns just the second paragraph.

[image]

---

I do not see the justification for the statement that we can find $\alpha(i,x)$ so that $gd_i{x}$ and $d_ig{x}$ become equal in $X_{\alpha(i,x)}$, i.e., that the two become equal in the colimit. Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is essentially that this is because $i_\alpha g = f$, and $f$ and $i_\alpha$ are maps of simplicial sets.

Therefore, if we fix $i$ and $x$, 
$$i_\alpha (gd_ix)=fd_ix=d_ifx = d_i(i_\alpha g)x = i_\alpha(d_igx).$$
In other words, $gd_ix$ and $d_igx$ are equal in the colimit, so we can find some $\alpha(i,x)$ as claimed.